# How do I define subclasses?

Tags: css

[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2VYj/2/) shows my problem.

How would I define a subclass of `class="line"` in the thml and css structure so that the subclass would not have a border-top-style as shown in Example 2?

Thank you.

EDIT: I hope [that this](http://jsfiddle.net/b2VYj/3/) is how it works. Any comments?

Comment: You should really be more careful with your selectors. What you have there is "Any element with the class 'text' which has as an ancestor element any element with the class 'line'." What you probably want to say is `div.line>div.text` which is "A div with the class text which is an immediate descendant of a div with the class line." For your particular page what you have may be sufficient, but being careful not to accidentally select more elements than you intended is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as a subclass in CSS. You could add another class

```
class="line line-no-top"
```

and then define line-no-top in CSS:

```
.line-no-top{ border-top-style:none; }
```

to achieve the effect.

Your problem is that you have a div with a top border and inside that a div with some text. You're trying to turn off the top border of the outer div by setting border:none on the inner div, which won't work. You have to apply the class that turns the border off to the outer div.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just found the solution.